# Is there any way to remove indexedDB if database name is LokiCatalog

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, lokijs

Is there any way to  remove indexedDB from chrome console for cordova application if database name is LokiCatalog?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can delete it using indexeddb api "deleteDatabase". So the code to delete the database "LokiCatalog will be" -

```
var DBDeleteRequest = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase("LokiCatalog");

DBDeleteRequest.onerror = function(event) {
  console.log("Error deleting database.");
};

DBDeleteRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  console.log("Database deleted successfully");

  console.log(event.result); // should be undefined
};
```

For more you can take a look here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory/deleteDatabase

If you dont want to deal with indexeddb apis, you can use some indexeddb wrapper like - [JsStore](http://jsstore.net/).

Comment: It did not help. Database still exists. I think this is because indexedDB is wrapped with lokijs and the name if database is not LokiCatalog. But I am not sure :(

Comment: If db name is not the one you are deleting that means db still exist, so is the data. Can you open the database with the same name, you want to delete and get all data from a particular table ? This will make sure - that db name is same or not.

Comment: I found the problem. Your solution is good. Thanks. 
The problem is that the db is blocked by something.

Answer (score 1):

[`indexedDB.deleteDatabase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory/deleteDatabase) can delete an IndexedDB database, just make sure you are listening for all events, so you get notified if the DB is blocked or else.

Here's an example of a promisified `deleteDatabase` version that listens to all events.

```
function deleteDb(dbName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const deleteDbRequest = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(dbName);
        deleteDbRequest.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
            console.log('delete error', e);
            reject(e);
        });
        deleteDbRequest.addEventListener('blocked', (e) => {
            console.log('delete blocked', e);
            reject(e);
        });
        deleteDbRequest.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', (e) => {
            console.log('delete upgradeneeded', e);
            reject(e);
        });
        deleteDbRequest.addEventListener('success', (e) => {
            console.log('delete success', e);
            resolve(e);
        });
    })
}
```

This is just an example. You may want to behave differently (i.e. not necessarily `reject`) on the `upgradeneeded` event, for instance.

Example usage:

```
deleteDb('LokiCatalog')
    .then(r => console.log('success', r))
    .catch(e => console.error('oops', e));
```